# Fading the opacity of a background when carousel changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I am working on getting a carousel background fade in when I move to next carousel item. Fading in works with CSS and JS in the code below on page load, but using jQuery to get this to work on change is not working.

**JS-CSS:**

```
function doCarouselBlur(imgEl) {
var root = imgEl.closest('.anlNoCarouselRoot');
if (root.length > 0) {
    console.log('position: ' + JSON.stringify(root.position()));
    console.log('width: ' + root.width());
    console.log('height: ' + root.height());
    console.log('src: ' + imgEl.attr('src'));
    var width = root.width() + 160;
    var height = root.height() + 40;
    root.find('.carouselBackground').css({
        'top': root.position().top - 20,
        'left': root.position().left - 120,
        'opacity': '0.92',
        'transition': 'opacity 2s ease',  // THIS WORKS ON LOAD BUT WON'T WORK FOR ON CHANGE
        'background-image': 'url(' + imgEl.attr('src') + ')',
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'z-index': '-10',
        'clip': 'rect(20px, ' + width + 'px, ' + height + 'px, 20px)',
    });

    root.find('.dark-carousel-overlay').css({
        'top': root.position().top - 20,
        'left': root.position().left - 120,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'z-index': '-8'
    });
  };
}
```

**ADDED JQUERY FOR TRANSITION ON CHANGE:**

```
$('div.carouselBackground').on('change', function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', '0');
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', '0.92');
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code, if possible in jsfiddle?

Comment: @AlexanderDayan not sure if I can add to a jsfiddle...I mainly wonder if my jQuery addition should be written different. If I was to comment out the transition in the first code and use `$('div.carouselBackground').fadeTo('slow', '0'); $('div.carouselBackground').fadeTo('slow', '0.92');` that works for onload

Comment: The problem is in that line:
$('div.carouselBackground').on('change', function() {
but it's difficult to help you if you provide only a function code, with no some related html at least.